# How to have a role name of auth user in laravel

Tags: laravel

I start to use laravel and I want to know, How to show in view the name role of auth user.
For the moment I have just the role id when I do auth()->user()->role_id.
Thanks for you help.

Comment: Try to read documentation if you are using spatie package.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code into your user model

```
public function role()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Role', 'role_id');
    }
```

than you can see your data

```
 uth()->user()->role
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Test My Sample In Project

go to User Modal and edit file
Please add code

```
public function Role(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Role','role_id','id');
}
```

This way you can get role information you want

```
$query=User::with('Role')->first();

$query->Role->name
```

Surely this will solve your problem